# Can you identify this plant with toothed leaves?

Tags: identification

Are you able to identify this plant that is in my front yard? It is about 70cm high at the moment, and grows out in separate stems that come out from the ground that you see here. I live in Melbourne, Australia. Thank you

[image: The plant in my front yard]

Comment: Quite possibly Banksia. (B serrata? integrifolia?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe *Banksia prionotes*, common name Acorn banksia - see what the flowers look like when they arrive. Image and info here https://www.bgpa.wa.gov.au/about-us/information/our-plants/plants-in-focus/2712-banksia-prionotes

Comment: Thanks @Polypipe and Bamboo. After some obsessive searching last night I came across Banksia spinulosa var. collina which I think might be it. If it ends up with those candlestick flowers I won't be removing it.